# Seeking for general class for a combo box & list box to reduce code

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have two different lists in my application. Each for a combo box and a list box. I am using below reusable code for inserting items in the controls. Right now, I am using two different functions as seen. Is there any general class for a combo box and a list box, so that I can do my work in a single function?

```
public void AddItemsComboBox(ComboBox combobox, List<string> list)
    {
        foreach (string s in list)
        {
            if (!combobox.Items.Contains(s))
            {
                combobox.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddItemsListBox(ListBox listbox, List<string> list)
    {
        foreach (string s in list)
        {
            if (!listbox.Items.Contains(s))
            {
                listbox.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error have you got?

Comment: @MANISHKUMARCHOUDHARY I don't get any error.. I just want to reduce my code in a single function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic controls if the methods are same.

```
public void AddItems(dynamic control, List<string> list)
{
    foreach (string s in list)
        if (!control.Items.Contains(s))
            control.Items.Add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ListBox` and `ComboBox` classes both derive from a common ancestor, namely `ListControl`. Unfortunately, that's not where the `Items` property is defined, so the best I can come up with requires a bit of run-time type checking:

```
public void AddItems(ListControl lb, List<string> list)
{
    ListBox listBox = lb as ListBox;
    ComboBox comboBox = lb as ComboBox;
    foreach (string s in list)
    {
        if (listBox != null && !listBox.Items.Contains(s))
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(s);
        }
        else if (comboBox != null && !comboBox.Items.Contains(s))
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
}
```